# Compare model fit (-2 log likelihood), is my model significantly better?

Tags: chi-squared-test, goodness-of-fit, likelihood

I have 6 models with -2 log likelihood as an indication of model fit. The fit increases from model 1 to 6, with model 1 having the worst fit (lowest -2 log likelihood) and 6 the best fit. How do I test whether the fit of one model is significantly better than the other(s)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38248595/likelihood-ratio-test-in-python/69215955#69215955 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51803027/likelihood-ratio-test-in-r/69219141#69219141

Comment: Are your models nested?  If so, maybe https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/473433/use-of-likelihood-ratio-test-anova-for-significance-testing

Answer (score 0):

If the models are nested then you can you use [Wilks' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilks%27_theorem) to perform a [likelihood-ratio test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood-ratio_test).

Answer (score -1):

I think log-likelihood does not have distribution so there is no such test for log-likelihood value. You can compare with other criteria such as AIC and BIC altogether and make a discrete choice which model would be the best.