# Use of likelihood ratio test/ANOVA for significance testing

Tags: linear-model, likelihood-ratio

I've read that likelihood ratio tests comparing two models (one with and without a predictor) should be performed to determine whether a variable of interest is statistically significant, rather than using the p-values for estimates of individual predictors from the summary() function of a linear model.

I've also read that this is only necessary when the model includes factors with more than two levels.

I am trying to find out whether the second statement is correct but have been unable to find out whether or not LRT/ANOVA is necessary for models with factors containing only two levels.

Please could anyone advise?

Comment: A likelihood ratio test generates a p-value, so this is question does not make sense to me. What is the context of what you read?

Comment: Thanks for replying, and I'm sorry that I wasn't clear. I have tried to make the question clearer.

Comment: For assessing the effects of individual predictors in a linear model, I have been told that we should not report the p-values given for each estimate by the summary() function, and that instead a likelihood ratio test that compares a model with and without a predictor should be used. I'm unsure whether this is necessary.

Comment: What are your null and alternative hypotheses? What kind of model are you using, vanilla OLS linear regression with constant-variance, normal errors? Depending on what you're doing, it could be reasonable to use either likelihood ratio testing or the Wald test of which classic ANOVA is one example.

Comment: Just a regular linear model - lm() in R - with four binary predictors and one continuous variable. I want to report the results of the full model, but have been told that I shouldn't use the p-values from the model summary to support accepting my hypothesis. I've read that it's usual to use a likelihood ratio test, and have been told to compare models with and without each predictor. I'm confused about whether and why this is necessary.

Comment: One source of my confusion is that I heard that it is only necessary to do this when the categorical variables contain more than two levels (as the model summary only gives values for each level and not the overall effect of that factor) but it's possible that I misinterpreted this.

Comment: What are your null and alternative hypotheses? And who is telling you to do likelihood ratio testing instead of Wald/ANOVA?

Comment: My null hypothesis is that the variables do not have an effect (apart from the continuous variable, which is in the model because I expected it to have an effect). I thought ANOVA could be used to perform an LRT?

Answer (score 3):

You can test the nested models using either Wald or likelihood ratio testing. Wald would be the standard way to go with a linear model. The reduced model only has the continuous predictor, and then the full model has the continuous predictor plus the others. Your null is that the other predictors do not influence the outcome, and the alternative is that they do influence the outcome.

Wald and likelihood ratio methods test these hypotheses in somewhat different ways but more-or-less aim to justify the inclusion of additional predictors. The fit never decreases when you add predictors, but is the increase in fit worth the added complexity?

Wald compares the ratio of squared errors to an $F$-distribution (sound familiar from ANOVA?), while likelihood ratio compares the ratio of likelihoods to a $\chi^2$ distribution. I'm going from memory and might have missed some details, but these should look somewhat familiar.

$$\text{**Wald Test**}$$

$$\dfrac{(SSE_{reduced}-SSE_{full})/(n-p_{full})}{SSE_{reduced}/(p_{full}-p_{reduced})}\sim F_{n-p_{full}, p_{full}-p_{reduced}}$$

$$\text{**Likelihood-ratio Test**}$$

$$[LLik_{full} - LLik_{reduced}] \sim \chi^2_{\text{difference in parameter counts of the nested full and reduced models}}$$

Comment: Thank you. So it's always necessary to use a post hoc model comparison test when running a linear model with more than one predictor?

Comment: No. What part of my post makes you think that? I want to edit that to clarify. The reason you would do this is because you went into the model construction with a hypothesis in mind, essentially doing something like ANCOVA.

Comment: I think the main reason why I was confused by your post is because I was already very confused about it! The source of my confusion was originally a reviewer saying that I'd done an LRT when I hadn't (unless just running a linear model can be referred to as such??), and now my supervisors are expecting me to do an LRT. I wanted to find out whether it was necessary or whether reporting my summary() results was sufficient.

Comment: R’s summary(model) command won’t do this test for you. The p-values come from Wald testing each parameter, checking how the SSE improves when each is included in a model that did not contain it (nested models). You want to do something similar but examine how the fit changes when you add in all of the binary variables to a model that only contained the continuous predictor. You can do that with either Wald or LR testing. The R package lmtest implements both: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lmtest/lmtest.pdf. What exactly did the reviewer say? (Perhaps consult with a stat grad student.)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you're interested in testing. Let's consider a linear model with a two-category predictor $X$ and some response $Y$. The model is:

$y_{i} = \beta_{0} + \beta_{1}d_{i} + \varepsilon_{i}$

Where $d_{i}$ is an indicator/dummy variable which could be written as $d_{i} = \mathbb{I}(x=1)$. That is: It takes on the value 0 for one category, and the value 1 for the other category. You fit this in R using the command `lm( y ~ x )`.

The `summary()` command in R is going to test all of the individual coefficients, in this case $\beta_{0}$ and $\beta_{1}$. The `anova()` command (comparing the previous `lm` call with a second `lm` call `lm( y ~ 1 )`) will perform a test on all the coefficients of $X$. For the case of a two-category predictor, this is the same test as the individual test from `summary()`.

Now consider a 3-category predictor. With three categories, we need two dummy variables, so the model is:

$y_{i} = \beta_{0} + \beta_{1}d_{1,i} + \beta_{2}d_{2,i} + \varepsilon_{i}$

We can run the same codes as before. Before, the individual test from `summary()` was (or rather, included) a test on $\beta_{1}$, which was equivalent with a test on the entire $X$ predictor. with the 3-category predictor, none of the individual tests are testing "all" of $X$. But the `anova()` test is assessing the "total effect" of $X$, so the tests are no longer the same.

If we consider four models:

- Full: $y_{i} = \beta_{0} + \beta_{1}d_{1,i} + \beta_{2}d_{2,i} + \varepsilon_{i}$
- Reduced 1b: $y_{i} = \beta_{0} + \beta_{2}d_{2,i} + \varepsilon_{i}$
- Reduced 1a: $y_{i} = \beta_{0} + \beta_{1}d_{1,i} + \varepsilon_{i}$
- Reduced 2: $y_{i} = \beta_{0} + \varepsilon_{i}$

The `summary()` output is comparing the Full model to Reduced models 1a and 1b (ignoring the test on the intercept). the `anova()` model is comparing the Full model to Reduced model 2. For a two-category predictor these will align, for three or more categories, they do not.

The individual tests may still be useful with 3+ categories, but it depends on what you're wanting to test.

You can see it in action with some examples. Change `kk` from 2 to 3, for instance. Notice that for `kk <- 2` the p-value for the predictor in `summary()` will be the same as that from `anova()`, and if you square the t test statistic, you'll get the LRT test statistic. When you switch to `kk <- 3`, that will no longer be the case.

```
nn <- 10
kk <- 2

gg <- rep( LETTERS[1:kk], each=nn )

xx <- runif( nn*kk , 0, 10 )
yy <- rnorm( nn*kk, rep( c(10,12,14)[1:kk] , each=nn), 3 )


summary( lm( yy ~  gg ) )
anova( lm( yy ~  gg ),
       lm( yy ~ 1 ) )
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply. I assume you meant to include xx in the model? Even so, it makes sense. So, for a model with only binary and continuous predictors, the p-values from the model summary can be reliably used and an LRT or similar test is not necessary?

Comment: Oh, yeah, I initially had xx in the model as well, but had decided to remove it for simplicity. You can put it back in and the results will still hold. In the mathematical models that I posted, that would just mean adding another beta*x term. And yes, for a binary predictor or continuous predictor, there's no difference between the tests (at least for the basic examples like this, in more complex models, there might be different asymptotic approximations used).